# Are you supposed to use a separate header file with .mm files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode if you are mixing c++ with objective c are you not supposed to use separate header file from the implementation? How do you declare c++ instance variables if it is supposed to be separate? You can't #include a c++ header file into a non .mm file or else you get compile errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured out that you can extend the interface in the .mm file